# how fetching a set of string from a string in regex

Tags: php, regex

im not a Regex Expert and tried searching for solution but I **really** cant find one. this is kind of a basic regex question. hope you could help me

consider this as a **string**

```
    $ret_value = ($norm_string_value == 'true' ? true : false);

    $line = trim($line);
                if (strlen($line)==0 || $line[0]==';' || $line[0] == '#') {
                    continue;
                } 
    $foobar = hello_world($foo) == 'bar'
```

Im using Netbeans IDE and searching a piece of code using the Find functionality..

my expected match would be:

```
    $norm_string_value == '
    $line[0]==';'
    $line[0] == '
    hello_world($foo) == '
```

my current regex is like this `[$].*? == '`
and what im currently getting as a result is:

```
    $ret_value = ($norm_string_value == '
    $line)==0 || $line[0]==';' || $line[0] == '
    $foobar = hello_world($foo) == '
```

you see im having a problem with that dollar symbol and that hello_world..- i dont know how to include that in my regex

Comment: And what about `===`? What about comparing with numbers? Write some more examples or add, what really are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Perhaps `\S*[$][^$]*==\s*'` is the regex you are looking for?

Comment: Perhaps `(?:\w+\()?\$[^$\r\n]*={2,3}\h*'(?:;')?` https://regex101.com/r/XxTy7l/1/

Comment: @freeek honestly I only need ==.. not ===

Comment: How about: `\$\w+\h*==\h*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current example data, to get all 4 matches you might use this slightly updated pattern taking the surrounding whitespace chars into account as well:

```
(?:\w+\()?\$[^$\r\n]*\h*==\h*'(?:;')?
```

In parts

- `(?:\w+\()?` Optionally match 1+ word chars followed by `(`
- `\$` Match `$~
- `[^$\r\n]*` Match 0+ times any char except `$` or a newline
- `\h*==\h*` Match `==` surrounded by 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `'(?:;')?` Optionally match `;'`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yXf5W2/1)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments! I found the answer:

```
(?:\w+\()?\$[^$\r\n]* == \h*'(?:;')?
```

its kinda a modified version of The Fourth Bird's Answer

```
(?:\w+\()?\$[^$\r\n]*={2,3}\h*'(?:;')?
```

just added some space and removed the {2,3} and made it == instead

actually the real purpose of this is to make my code's condition to `===` instead of `==`
the single quote reassures me that the left pair is a string so i need to cast `(string)` on it.

Radagast81's answer was "ALMOST" what i needed and i prefer it more than Fourth Bird's since it was much simpler/shorter. tried to modify it but i cant make it work

```
\S*[$][^$]*==\s*'
```

one of my samples matched:

```
($norm_string_value == '
```

and i dont need that 'parenthesis' included. just:

```
$norm_string_value == '
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you want to find all 4 matches I think it needs a small adjustment `(?:\w+\()?\$[^$\r\n]*\h*==\h*'(?:;')?` https://regex101.com/r/yXf5W2/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird bro you can post it as an answer so i can mark it accordingly (y) your a life saver!

Comment: I have added it with an explanation.